# Constraining Parameters in Bayesian Linear Regression using RJAGS

Tags: r, constraints, bayesian, jags

I'm building a hierarchical bayesian linear regression model using RJAGS, and I want to constrain the sum of the values of three parameters to be normally distributed with mean 1.3. That is:

The model is:

Y = B1 * X1 + B2 * X2 + B3 * X3 + ... + BN* XN

And,

B1 + B2 + B3 ~ dnorm(1.3, 1/(0.2)^2)

Is it possible to do that? Using a line of code to distribute the sum of parameters as in the previous line doesn't seem to work.

A second best alternative would be to fully constrain the parameters (B1 + B2 + B3 = 1.3), but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to re-express `B2` and `B3` in terms of `B1`? This would make it easier to constrain values, as only `B1` would need to be constrained, and perhaps another splitting parameter.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is by analogy to hierarchical "ANOVA"-style models. In those models, each group mean is a deflection $\beta_j$ from baseline $\beta_0$ and the deflections are forced to sum to zero. The analogy to your case is re-coding the three regression coefficients as sum-to-zero deflections from a baseline coefficient, and having the baseline come from a normal prior with mean of 1.3.

You can see examples of JAGS model specifications for ANOVA in Chapter 19 of [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis 2nd Ed.](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/) The idea for adapting them here is something like this (I've suppressed the i index):

```
mu <- sum( b[1:3]*x[1:3] )
# Prior on unconstrained baseline a0 and deflections a[j]:
a0 ~ dnorm( 1.3 , 1/0.2^2 )
for ( j in 1:3 ) { a[j] ~ dnorm(0,1/10^2) }
# Convert a0,a[j] to sum-to-zero b0,b[j]:
for ( j in 1:3 ) { m[j] <- a0 + a[j] }
b0 <- mean( m[1:3] )
for ( j in 1:3 ) { b[j] <- m[j] - b0 }
```

At least, that's an idea...